# Android: How to change lots of string names in strings.xml easily?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, refactoring

Suppose I have 1000s of

```
<string name="somename">Some string</string>
```

in my strings.xml file.

How I see that the name attribute needs to be changed to something sensible for lots of these entries.

Is there an easy way to do this in eclipse or any another tool? Or will I have to write my own tool to do this?

Comment: Should have been done right at the first place!

Comment: Do `Cntrl+H` go to `File Search` specify the text and hit replace to replace it one by one

Comment: Should each one of your 1000 entries have a different attribute value? If so, I don't see how you could use any tool in an "easy way" for this job... If the values are repeated, you can use the editor's replacement feature

Answer (score 0):

just use replace feature of any editor (also works in multiple files in most of editors, in case you have multiple xmls).

Replace **name="somename"** by **name="othername"** or **name=** by **newAttrName=** as per your requirement.

If you worry about that the same string can be encountered elsewhere which you do not want to change (like comments), You need to write your own logic I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can install MOTODEV Studio for Android. It has bunch of things including Android Localization Files Editor

[Here](http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/us-en/motodev_lp.html) is the link for that.Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools to do this, I usually take help of Notepad ++, if you want to change all the 1000 names to a single name,

Else I write a program using XMLBeans to change the attribute based on some logic. This takes very less time and is re-usable in case such need arises in future.